# (keyup.enter) triggered twice | Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So I have an HTML with increment and decrement functionality on button/enter click. Button (click) works as expected however on (keyup.enter) increment function is triggered twice.

When I press Tab + enter on keyboard (keyup.enter) and (click) both events are triggered which is calling the function twice

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" style="text-align:center">
        <h2> Increment/Decrement Functionality</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin: 40px">
    <div class="col-sm">
        Increment All <button  (click)="incrementAll()" (keyup.enter)="incrementAll()"> +
        </button>
        Decrement All
        <button (click)="decrementAll()" (keyup.enter)="decrementAll()"> - </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin: 40px">
    <div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let num of countNumbers; let i = index" style="margin: 20px">
        <input name="countNumbers_{{i}}" type="number" [(ngModel)]="num.number" #ngModel>
        <button (click)="decrement(i)" (keyup.enter)="decrement(i)"[ngClass]="{'disabledIcon': num.number === 0 }"style="margin:20px"> -
  </button>
        <button (click)="increment(i)"
     (keyup.enter)="increment(i)"> +
  </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
increment(index) {
    this.countNumbers[index].number += 1;
}

decrement(index) {
    if (this.countNumbers[index].number > 0) {
        this.countNumbers[index].number -= 1;
    }
}

incrementAll() {
for (let i = 0; i < this.countNumbers.length; i++) {
  this.countNumbers[i].number += 1;
}
}
decrementAll() {
for (let i = 0; i < this.countNumbers.length; i++) {
  if (this.countNumbers[i].number > 0) {
    this.countNumbers[i].number -= 1;
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-koxkg3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: The event is not being raised twice. When you select a control with Tab and press Enter, a Click event is raised. If it were not, many web sites would be impossible to interact with without a mouse. As you are also listening explicitly for the Enter Up event, it would be incorrect and confusing for that event to not also be raised. Why not just use Click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, an HTML button can be "clicked" on with enter (e.g. for people who use the keyboard to navigate the form).

In your code, if a button is focused (if you've clicked on it before), and you press enter, these things happen:

1. The default "click" event is registered, so you get an increment.
2. your `(keyup.enter)="incrementAll()"` is registered, so you get a second increment.

A quick fix is to get rid of `(keyup.enter)="incrementAll()"`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm" style="text-align:center">
            <h2> Increment/Decrement Functionality</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin: 40px">
        <div class="col-sm">
            Increment All <button  (click)="incrementAll()"> +
            </button>
            Decrement All
            <button (click)="decrementAll()"> - </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin: 40px">
        <div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let num of countNumbers; let i = index" style="margin: 20px">
            <input name="countNumbers_{{i}}" type="number" [(ngModel)]="num.number" #ngModel>
            <button (click)="decrement(i)"[ngClass]="{'disabledIcon': num.number === 0 }"style="margin:20px"> -
      </button>
            <button (click)="increment(i)"> +
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've got it right but I wouldn't call this solution a quick fix. This is the most straightforward solution and I don't see any drawbacks as the event handlers registered are identical

Comment: @AluanHaddad Their solution is stateless and their context is leaking. I'd recommend them to store the counter in a stateful component instead of a global array for better scalability: What happens when they introduce a 'reorder' feature? Now they have to write extra code to recreate the global array. This is just one example.

Comment: I see what you mean, although I prefer stateless Solutions Wherever possible . However what I mean is that it is indeed correct to remove the Enter up event handler. Registering them both is unnecessary and mistaken

Comment: I agree with you that stateless is powerful but can be confusing and adds more work in this example. What do you think about using stateful components to keep the counter, then their context would store a "global" data object with their results? So instead of looping through an array, they can access a json object with their results in one place, e.g. `{counter1uuid: 1, counter2uuid: 2}`. That way they don't even have to worry about maintaining a component array and they get an easy to read output object that is flat.

Comment: I would actually be inclined to provide the current values as an `@Output()` from the component. However that might not satisfy every use case. In Angular one would typically use a service instead of an application scoped variable (`export const state = {}`), but there are definitely complexity trade-offs. I definitely would not use a global variable (`window.state = {}`). Anyway, an interesting discussion but somewhat off-topic I think

Comment: We did derail quite a bit from the original question. Thanks for indulging me.

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `keyup`, `keydown` is working for me.